# checking for multiple conditions in python

Tags: if-statement, python-3.6

I have a text file and some where in that file I have a line with the following content

`xxxx xxxx y = 4.63456`

where xxxx represents the part the line I am not interested in. My goal is to extract that y = 4.63456 value and write it to a new text file. Here is what I have so far.

```
import os
import re


my_absolute_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

with open('testfile', 'r') as helloFile, open('newfile32','a') as out_file:

 for line in helloFile:

     numbertocheck= []

     if 'x' in line and ' = ' in line and numbertocheck==type(float) in line:

        out_file.write(line)
```

The code creates the file but the file is empty. Is this the right way of checking for the conditions in the if statement? FWIW, if i removed the two conditionals at the end and wrote `if x in line:` the code works fine but prints out the entire line.

Comment: `numbertocheck==type(float) in line` looks like it's missing something. That's doesn't look like it's what you want. What's your intent there?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I replied to the comment from Julian down below and I have tried to state my intentions. Appreciate the response.

Comment: I think you mean `type(numbertocheck) == float`, since right now you're checking what type `float` is. Also again, why do you have `in line` at the end? And as they noted, `numbertocheck` is a list, so it will never be a float. What is `numbertocheck`? I think you're going to need to clarify your intent further.

Comment: Why not just `if "y = " in line": out_file.write(line[:4])`? The `[:4]` drops the "y = " part.

Answer (score 0):

`numbertocheck==type(float)` is probably your culprit.  When you get to that point in the code, `numbertocheck` is a list, and so it will never be of type float.  You can check this by running `type(numbertocheck)`.

It's unclear what you're wanting to do with the empty list `numbertocheck` and why you need it to be float.  If you offer more info we can probably better guide you.

**EDIT based on comment:**

Let's make the assumption that your desire with `numbertocheck` is to check whether the `4.63456` value within `xxxx xxxx y = 4.63456` is a valid float or not.

You need to extract the float value from the `line` string.  Regex is suited for this, but the exact answer depends on what you know or don't know about possible values in a given line.

If you're certain the number will always have a decimal point in it,

```
import re
numbertocheck = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", line)
```

will extract the "float" value.  If you can't guarantee a decimal point, use `re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", line)` instead.

This may return multiple numbers if they exist in your line.  If it's possible for there to be numbers elsewhere in your `line` (such as in the `xxxx xxxx` part), and if you only care about the number at the end of your line,  then this might work.

```
for line in helloFile:

    numbers_in_line = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", line)

    # Make sure a number was found
    if len(numbers_in_line) == 0:
        continue
    else:
        try:
            last_num = float(numbers_in_line[-1])
        except ValueError:
            continue
    # By this point, you've confirmed if a number was found and if it's a float

    if 'x' in line and ' = ' in line:
        out_file.write(line)
```

Note that this will allow numbers without decimal points to count as a valid number; you can modify it if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was trying to get python to check for a float. If it is a float number, to include it in the output file. The problem is that that number is going to check from file to file so that `numbertocheck` was suppose to be a general representation. I just dont know a better way of doing this.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment to offer some suggestions.  It's the best I can do without a clearer picture of what you're going for.  If you find it helpful, please upvote and/or accept.